# Updating a text field from the URL from WebKit

Tags: cocoa

First off let me say that I am VERY new to COCOA but I am learning.  I have a simple web browser built.  It loads a default page, takes URLs from a text field, even has google search.  The problem I'm running in to is updating the textfeild with the current URL.  I have the code as follows...

In the .h is...

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface MustangAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    NSTextField *googleSearch;
    WebView *webView;
    NSTextField *addressBar;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *googleSearch;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet WebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *addressBar;

- (IBAction)googleSearch:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)homeAction:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)addressBar:(id)sender;
@end
```

In the .m I have a bunch so I'll put in what I think is relevant here...

```
#import "MustangAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MustangAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize googleSearch;
@synthesize webView;
@synthesize addressBar;

- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [webView request];
    NSURL *currentURL = [currentRequest URL];
    addressBar.stringValue = currentURL.absoluteString;
}
```

The code for the above method never get's called.  Like I said, I'm very new to OBC & Cocoa but have been programming in things like Perl for many years.  Seems like I'm missing some connectivity because I get a warning with the above code that states WebView may not respond to the request.  I dug around to find that code but it still seems like I'm missing something...

Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Just CTRL + drag the -frameLoadDelegate from the IB to the App Delegate of your application, Mustang
use -didFinishLoadForFrame for the URL
and if you need the title use, -didRecieveTitle.

Hope it helped !